# Accessing Thumbnail images of bing videos

Tags: image, video, bing

With YouTube URLs such as (1) I can extract the videoID (in this case, mNLuq0lW50k) and then build another URL (2) in order to get a thumbnail for the video to put into an image source tag at some later point.

My question is, does Microsoft's Bing have a similar domain for thumbnail images? something like (3), or will I need some way of generating them myself?

(1) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNLuq0lW50k

(2) http://img.youtube.com/vi/mNLuq0lW50k/0.jpg

(3) http://img.bing.com/mNLuq0lW50k/img.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up a couple of the video thumbnails:

[Thumbnail 1](http://ts1.mm.bing.net/videos/thumbnail.aspx?q=1451323294336&id=944fd515648e56fe260aba758d3e69eb&bid=fadNHQtlLTaybQ&bn=Thumb&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGryUcJ2jTo)

[Thumbnail 2](http://ts2.mm.bing.net/videos/thumbnail.aspx?q=1502863753613&id=864a1f7b43f34ff19f9b1c54969460f5&bid=49kfY9ivPC5pvA&bn=Thumb&url=http://www.nbc.com/the-biggest-loser/video/yoplait/948221)

It looks like bing fluctuates between a few different subdomains (at least ts1.mm.bing.net and ts2.mm.bing.net).

Comment: Was there a way of determining this at all from the URL of the video?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the bing thumbnail from the youtube video url.  But if you want to get the youtube thumbnail then you can do: `http://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-video-id>/default.jpg`